# Setting dateTime.ToString() format centrally

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, date

How do i set the `DateTime` format centrally so that at any time if I use a `DateTime.ToString()` in my code I get string in the ISO format(eg:`2008-2-19 01:00:00`) or (`2008-2-19`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) to control the format when using [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)

Once you have set the CurrentCulture on your Current Thread then try the following:

```cs
DateTimeFormatInfo format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(format.FullDateTimePattern);
```

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture (and .CurrentUICulture).

Comment: The culture is being set but it the dateTime format doesnt change. Check edit above

Comment: Hey Barry...i want to do it without using an overload...like this DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
This is because there are times when im not stating this in my code...eg: foreach( row in dataTable) {jsonwriter.writestring(row.tostring();}

Comment: I had to set ShortDatePattern and LongTimePattern to get ToString output exactly what I want, but that might have something to do with using mysql datetime...

Comment: If after setting that, you create a child thread, does it inherit the setting?

Comment: @EdAvis To affect all threads you should set `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property - this will ensure any new threads are the same culture. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Albin and Barry's answers iv got the following piece to code to set the Time format centrally in the Global.asax.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            CultureInfo standardizedCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            standardizedCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
            standardizedCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
            standardizedCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";           
            standardizedCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern  = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = standardizedCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = standardizedCulture;
        }
```

Comment: I believe that LongDatePattern = "s"; or "o"; will also do the job.

Comment: Ideas derived from 1)http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingEvilOverridingSystemDateTimesDefaultToString.aspx
2)http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/125490-ISO-8601-date-formats-in-ASPNET/

Answer (score 2):

You can add the time format as parameter to the tostring, i always use this for reference

```
Dim d = DateTime.Parse("2008-2-19 01:00:00")
Assert.AreEqual("2008-2-19 01:00:00", d.ToString("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Regards

Iain

Answer (score 2):

You should update the [`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) property.

This affects all `DateTime.ToString()` in the current thread.

Comment: Im setting both currentculture and uiculture to the one mentioned in the edit...The culture is being set along with the date format..but the dateTimeObj.ToString() continues to show it in en-us format...is something else required to be done other than just setting culture?

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension methods to extend datetime and create a ToISOString().

check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx on ways to accomplish it. In the extension method you can use parameters to format the string the way you need, then you can use DateTime.ToISOString(); You could also use cultureinfo as Barry said, but I don't know if it will fit your needs.

Comment: An extension with a different name will not help...I need it to be done on dateTime.ToString...This is so that when a datatable is being parsed to text/Json/Xml i want the format to be output in the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requested format i.e. `DateTIme.Now.ToString()` will have a **very** bad influence on your code readability (and maintainability..). Trying to override a well known behavior with a custom one is bad practice.
What I **do** consider a good way to use it is like so: `DateTIme.Now.ToString(IsDefaultFormat)`.
Now all you need to do is add an extension method to `DateTime` Which receives a `bool`, and if that bool is set to true, returns the `DateTime` using your "default format"

Comment: This is for a webservice im developing. I need the default format overridden to be sure im not sending it in any format but a singular standard unambiguous format. Besides the default locale is setting en-US date format which is very confusing for me since en-GB is followed here by the entire dev-team.